# Input from STDIN in Light Table Juno

Tags: julia, lighttable

I recently came across with this awesome IDE, Juno for Julia. I have setup the IDE properly and it is successfully connecting to Julia. However, I'm facing with a small problem: How am I supposed to get data from `STDIN` in Juno using say, `readline(STDIN)`?

Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lighttable / Juno doesn't supply an input console. But the Julia REPL (command line version) does. I find it best to have both open. In asyncronous mode you can put trow-away code, shell commands (";") and command help ("?") in REPL and keep-code in Juno, and they share variables. You just can't run async in this case, since you want Juno to stop and wait.

On Windows default setting, you need to Evaluation -> Kill Julia 
and then Ctrl+Space -> Julia: Connect to a running session. Leave out just '@async' when you want to wait for input.

If there is a better way already, I'd like to know too. Source: http://discuss.junolab.org/t/how-to-read-user-input-for-julia/110